# .slideUp() when hovering over anything else other than a specific div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I currently have this bit of code:

```
$(".usericon").hover(function () {
   if ($(".profile").is(":hidden")) {
   $(".profile").slideDown('slow');
   }
   });
```

which is currently sliding down the .profile div while hovering over .usericon (but only if it is hidden)

What I'd like it to do is when I hover over .profile nothing happens...but when I hover anywhere else other than .profile, it slides up.

How would I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you will need to stop the mouse event from bubbling when over profile or usericon and close the div when hovering the body.

here is some example code:

```
$(".usericon").mouseover( function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if ($(".profile").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".profile").slideDown('slow');
    }
});

$('.profile').mouseover( function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});


$('body').mouseover( function () {
    if ($(".profile").not(":hidden")) {
        $(".profile").slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: but if I go on .profile it will slideUp? I don't want this. I want it to slideUp if you hover over anything else but .profile

Comment: sorry, misinterpreted your question earlier, does the edit work for you?

Comment: yeah that's brilliant thanks - I would say $(document) works better though :)